# Has pt.h library been removed from arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to get a program to use protothreading and I've got an error at the include statement for the pt.h library stating that there is no such file or directory. This is how it's written in the program:

```
#include <pt.h>
```

Comment: Did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

`pt.h` has never, and will never, be part of the Arduino core distribution.  It is a completely separate third party library that you have to install yourself.

I think the library you want is [this one.](https://github.com/fernandomalmeida/protothreads-arduino)